# Listview not sorting when fragment is created

Tags: android, sorting, listview

I have a fragment that displays a listview using customAdapter from the database. On the toolbar I have a sort option which works fine. All I want is to retain the order of sorting whenever I reopen my app.

I have tried using shared preference to store the sorting order name (Like sorting in Ascending/ Descending / Date wise) and then setting the adapter to the list view but it doesn't work.

My onCreateView():

```
SharedPreferences preference =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    String sortval = preference.getString("Sort","Header");
    handler = new NotesHandler(getContext());
    list = handler.sortBy(sortval);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext(), list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

NotesHandler.java:

```
 public ArrayList<Notes> sortBy(String sortField)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" order by "+sortField+";",null);
    ArrayList<Notes> n = new ArrayList<>();

    if(c!= null && c.getCount()!=0)
    {
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                Notes note = new Notes(c.getString(0),c.getString(1),c.getString(2),c.getString(3),c.getString(4),c.getString(5));
                n.add(note);
            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    db.close();
    return n;
}
```

Kindly Help.

Comment: You should apply the filter to the list after fetching it from the database

Comment: what error u getting, u have to send sharedpref saved value if there is value in it  handler.sortBy(sortval);

Comment: @Pavan I have updated my code. sortVal is the saved value of the sharedPref. And I am not getting any error. My list just doesn't remain sorted when I close and then reopen my app

Comment: @MatPag Im sorry but i din't understand. Could you help

Comment: better u first debug and check

Comment: @Pavan Thank you, but I have checked by adding log statement. the log displays sorted array perfectly but only problem is the listview.

Comment: post ur class where and how u setting data?